# How do I set background color to white in libgdx?

Tags: colors, libgdx

How do I set the background color to white in LIBGDX using just `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(x,x,x,x);`???
if not then is it possible to draw a white batch as background but still render other actors on top of it?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
```